# HttpWebResponse contains no cookies

Tags: cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm using `HTTPWebRequest`/`HTTPWebResponse` to interact with the site (www.lockerz.com). So, I authenticate on the site:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.lockerz.com/auth/login");
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("handle=" + textBoxEmail.Text + "&password=" + textBoxPassword.Text);
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
Stream os = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Then I get the response:

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

I'm watching the requests\responses using Charles and it says that in the response there must be cookies, but when I try to make a list of the cookies I get it says that there are no cookies!

```
foreach(Cookie c in webResponse.Cookies) {
    writeToLog("Cookie Name: " + c.Name + " Value: " + c.Value);
    cc.Add(c);
}
```

I've tried adding a CookieContainer but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Did you tried to attach an CookieContainer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This may apply here, I have had this problem with sessions, so I will assume the same for cookies.

You are making a call to: http://www.lockerz.com/auth/login. But if a person goes to a page without the "www." part of the url, then their cookies won't survive being sent to the "www." site, because they are different sites (as far as the cookies are concerned).

I would just make the request to "/auth/login", that way, it won't matter what the user has as the url in their browser.

Hope this works.